# Set a virtual machine (Remote desktop) log out at certain point of time

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

I really have no idea to start from, that's why I turned in here to ask. So, there's the virtual account (Remote desktop connection on Windows) and it needs to be set to reboot or log out, i.e. every Saturday morning. It might be a script or any other way that will set this. As we have 1 server machine, to which connect around 10 developers (so 10 virtual accounts), this should be applied to all accounts. So, most desired solutions is: scheduled reboot OR (preferred) a script that logs out all users every week.

And idea I have is to make a script (I know only about `.bat` files, so other suggestions are welcome) that will schedule the run of a command which logs off the machine. And then populate this script on each account.

I am researching on my own atm, but since I have absolutely no knowledge in this area, so beginner's tips will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

could be a better way but i would probably...

create a batch script to run on a schedule that will reboot the machine, simply create a text file and enter the command *shutdown /r* save the file as a .bat file

then on task scheduler in windows create task, choose the day/time to run the script and choose the file you created, you may also choose who to run the script as etc.

here are some useful links:

[Make a simple batch file howto](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/)

[windows shutdown commands](http://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/573)

[Scheduling tasks in Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a scheduler method:

1. Go to Start > Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools and click on the Task Scheduler.
2. From the Action menu in Task Scheduler, click "Create Basic Task..."
3. In the "Create Basic Task Wizard" windows that pops up, Type in a title and a description. Something basic like "PC Shutdown."
4. Click "Next."
5. On the "Task Trigger" screen, choose the frequency with which you want the Shutdown PC to run.

6.On the "Daily" screen, enter the date and time you want your PC to shutdown. Click "Next."

7. On the "Action" screen, choose "Start a program" and click "Next."
8. On the "Start a Program" screen, type `C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe` in the "Program/script" text field.
9. In the Add arguments text field type `/s`.
10. Click "Next."
11. Confirm your settings on the Summary screen and click "Finish."